# Migration from JDK8 to JDK11 EXEC : error : invalid flag: -jni

Tags: java, c++, migration, java-native-interface, java-11

I am migrating my application from JDK8 to JDK11 and my application is using java native interface to create JNI headers. My command use Javah.exe for this purpose and I am aware that javah.exe was removed in Java 10 and no longer available. My command looks like this:

```
"$(JDK8_x86)\bin\javah.exe" -jni -d "$(ProjectDir)Source" -classpath "$(ProjectDir)..\..\dist\Avus_ESCD.jar" pii.AvusEcd.LibProxy.SensorCarrierProxy
```

Javah has been superseded by the -h option added to javac in JDK 8. So therefore I changed my command for JDK11 like this:

```
"$(JDK8_x86)\bin\javac.exe" -jni -h "$(ProjectDir)Source" -classpath "$(ProjectDir)..\..\dist\Avus_ESCD.jar" pii.AvusEcd.LibProxy.SensorCarrierProxy
```

but I am getting this error in Java11. Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

```
EXEC : error : invalid flag: -jni
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use --help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: According to the docs, for Java 8, you never needed to specify `-jni` since that's what `javah` did anyway.

Comment: without -jni i am getting this error : Class names, 'pii.AvusEcd.LibProxy.SensorCarrierProxy' are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested

Comment: Add `.java` to the class name.